# Getting around for loops in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a clustering algorithm in Python that I am trying to convert to PySpark (for parallel processing).

I have a dataset that contains regions, and stores within those regions. I want to perform my clustering algorithm for all stores in a single region.

I have a few for loops before getting to the ML. How can I modify the code to remove the for loops in PySpark? I have read for loops in PySpark are generally not a good practice - but I need to be able to perform the model on many sub-datasets. Any advice?

For reference, I"m currently looping (through Pandas DataFrames) like this pseudocode below:

```
for region in df_region: 
    for distinct stores in region: 
          [apply ML clustering algorithm]
```

Comment: I have exactly this same problem! Were you able to solve it using the solution?
I am trying to avoid doing the ML modeling in a pandas dataframe. Were you able to find a spark version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Search Built-in Algorithms**
You could consider looking up RDD-based built-in clustering algorithms first since they are usually common and were released via rigorous validation process.
[Clustering - RDD-based API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html)

If you're more familiar with DataFrame-based API, then you could go [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html) for a glance. And you might want to keep in mind as of Spark 2.0, the RDD-based APIs in the `spark.mllib` package have entered maintenance mode (no new features, only bug fixes). The primary ML API is now the DataFrame-based API in the `spark.ml` package.

**Implement Yourself**
*Pandas UDFs*
If you do have a model object already, consider Pandas UDFs since they have iterator support now (Since 3.0.0). Simply saying, it means a model won't be loaded for each row.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf

@pandas_udf(...)
def categorize(iterator):
  model = ... # load model
  for features in iterator:
    yield model.predict(features)

"""
GROUP BY in Spark SQL or window functions can be considered.
It depends on your scenarios, just remember DataFrames are still based on RDDs. 
They are immutable and are high-level abstraction.
"""
spark_df.withColumn("clustered_result", categorize("some_column")).show()
```

*RDD Exploring*
If, unfortunately, your intentional execution of the clustering algorithm is not included in the set of Spark built-in clustering algorithms and won't have a progress of training which means the generation of a model. You could consider converting the Pandas DataFrame into RDD data structures, then implementing your clustering algorithm. A rough process will be like the following:

```py
pandas_df = ....
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
.
.
clustering_result = spark_df.rdd.map{p => cluster_algorithm(p)}
```

*note1: It's only a rough progress, you might want to partition the whole dataset into few RDDs based on `region` then execute the clustering algorithm in each partitioned RDDs. Because the information of the clustering algorithm kinda not too clear, I could only give the advice based on some assumptions.*
*note2: RDD implementation should be your last option*

1. [RDD Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html)
2. 2017, Chen Jin, [A Scalable Hierarchical Clustering Algorithm Using Spark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrfD431KLwc)